# sequence sync option with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, postgres-11

I use pg_dump to backup and restore to target and manually sync (using setval function) sequences on tables. Is following an option to avoid manual sync or manual sync is always required?

```
pg_dump -s (schema-only) + pg_dump -a (only data from tables/LOB/Sequence Values)
```

And then i use pg_restore in same order which sync the sequences automatically

Comment: Define *manually sync sequences on tables* as update to question.

Comment: question updated adrian. I am using setval function to sync the sequences after pg_restore

Answer (score 1):

To get a script that sets the value of a sequence `seq`, you can run a data-only `pg_dump` for this sequence:

```bash
pg_dump -a -t seq
```